# Sass/CSS/Angular 1 - Select element same level into ng-class allowed class

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, ng-class

```
<button>
  <span>Search</span>
  <i class="fa"
     ng-class="$ctrl.pending ? 'fa-spinner' : 'fa-search'"
     aria-hidden="true">
  </i>
</button>
```

I want to select the `span` element if `fa-spinner` is allowed (by default `fa-search` which is taken)
In case the `span` element is below element `i` we can do:

HTML :

```
<button>
  <i class="fa"
     ng-class="$ctrl.pending ? 'fa-spinner' : 'fa-search'"
     aria-hidden="true">
  </i>
  <span>Search</span>
</button>
```

CSS :

```
.fa-spinner {
  font-size: 18px;

  & ~ span {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

How to reproduce the same result on the first HTML example ?

Comment: why don't you use `"$ctrl.pending ? 'fa-spinner' : 'fa-search'"` to add extra class to `span` for your styling needs?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan yes we can do that, but I would like to avoid adding an additional ng-class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/3953479 this might help you.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan yes +1, i will add another ng-class on the `span` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As selecting the previous sibling is not possible in CSS as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/3953479)

Best possible way to use `ng-class` similar to `i` for `span` as shown below:

```
<button>
    <span  ng-class="$ctrl.pending ? 'left-padding' : ''">Search</span>
    <i class="fa"
    ng-class="$ctrl.pending ? 'fa-spinner' : 'fa-search'"
    aria-hidden="true">
    </i>
</button>
//css
span.left-padding 
{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```